# How to align the Kendo Grid toolbar in righthand side

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

How to align the Kendo UI Grid toolbar buttons in righthand side.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Add the following CSS style:

```
.k-grid-toolbar a {
    float:right;
}
```

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/OnaBai/W42wK/

Comment: i tried that one. the columns is not aligning properly. for separating toolbar and column line is not displaying properly.

Comment: Please, check the style definition (I've modified it by adding an `a`). Check also the example.

Comment: The order is changing. I want same order like Add Save Reset. It is possilbe to adjust in css.. If rearrange buttons i can get same order but i want in see in css.

Comment: it is possible to assign 'save' & 'cancel' on right side, but 'Add New Record' remain at left side?